# While uninstalling python 3.9 using brew uninstall python - Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python". is popping up

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I had installed python3 using brew. This being my first time using terminal and using brew for that matter, I am not sure where I went wrong. after installing as suggested in another website, I used Pyenv to update the version of python and make the latest version the global one. but everytime I entered Python in terminal It showed Python 2.7

```
% python

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.16 (default, Jun 18 2021, 03:23:52) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.19.59.6) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploy on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Brew info gives the below.

```
% brew info python3
python@3.9: stable 3.9.7 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.9.rb
License: Python-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gdbm ✘, mpdecimal ✘, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✘, xz ✘
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages

tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately:
  brew install python-tk@3.9

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Analytics
install: 448,214 (30 days), 1,500,839 (90 days), 7,290,725 (365 days)
install-on-request: 157,960 (30 days), 522,744 (90 days), 2,279,934 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)'
```

The not installed part made me confused but when I used Pyenv versions and it shows below.

```
% pyenv versions
  system
* 3.9.7 (set by /Users/ronabraham/.pyenv/version)`
```

I also pasted the below into my .zshrc file.

`export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then eval "$(pyenv init -)" fi`

Even after this, Python command was still returning Python 2.7.

I again installed Python 3.9.7 from the official python downloads link. And tried uninstalling the Brew Python results as below.

```
% brew uninstall python3
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python3". Did you mean python@3.7, python@3.9, python@3.8, ipython, bpython, jython or cython?`

brew uninstall python@3.9
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python@3.9". Did you mean python@3.9, python-tk@3.9, python@3.8, python@3.7 or python-yq?
```

Will these 2 Pythons (brew python 3.9.7 and pkg installed 3.9.7 cause issues?) how can I remove the brew version or fix it and make it my default.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you probably missed closing `"` in your pyenv config setup.

This is mine for setting up pyenv in my local (I am using bash, so this is what I extracted from `~/.bash_profile`):

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

After the pyenv setup, you can open a new terminal session to use the pyenv version of python.

Also, you don't have to uninstall brew versions of python, as it is needed for brew formulae (the python CLI apps).